# Performance problems with Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, drivers, performance, intel

My computer's performance (A 2012 Macbook Pro, i7 with intel hd 4000), specifically with gaming, has been lacking in Ubuntu compared to my other operating systems, OS X and Windows. I feel like this could be due to my inability to get intel drivers, it being 14.04.2, but could there be something else? I have a swap partition and everything, configured as recommended, and have installed the LTS hardware enablement stuff. Is there anything else I should/could do?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing/updating the default graphics driver. From my experience, installing linux in a mac is better than keeping the default apple software, but as far as gaming is concerned, apple's software is simply better. That is because graphics drivers are better developed in windows and mac osx.